# How to analyze data with more than one associated categorical dependent variables?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, generalized-estimating-equations, multivariate-regression

I have **some dependent variables** related to the growth of a company having categories like (e.g. for variables indicating net profit, financial turnover etc.)

(1) decreasing,

(2) stable,

(3) increasing and

(4) rapidly increasing.

Now these variables are **associated** and **ordinal** in nature. I want to see the effect of a set of co-variates on these dependent variables. I understand that separate logistic regression will result in wrong formula of the variance and thus will produce wrong p-values. But what kind of regression should I run with **more than one associated dependent categorical variables**? Should that be a GEE model? Or anything else like multivariate regression (GLM)?

Can SPSS or R perform this?

Besides, I would like to have your suggestion regarding whether I should rather consider these variables as **nominal** and take **"stable"** as the **reference category** so that interpretations are more meaningful?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative analysis that can help you understand the variables that can best contribute to  differentiating the four types of firms under study is discriminant analysis. It is available under SPSS and gives a different perspective on the structure of contribution of the independent variables to the firms exhibiting different growth rates.
AA Gurkan